# NHibernate QueryOver WithSubQuery WhereAll clause

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

Houston we have a problem... No I guess its just me. :)

I am trying to do a Subquery on an NHibernate QueryOver object.
Queries without SubQueries work fine, but when a SubQuery is added everything falls apart.

**EDIT1:**
**What I want to accomplish is to select all users where all the relations to containers have the AccountStatus property set to DELETED**

```
var queryOver = session.QueryOver<User>();

queryOver.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.UserHasContainer).IsNotEmpty
         .JoinQueryOver<ContainerUser>(x => x.UserHasContainer)
         .WithSubquery.WhereAll(x => x.AccountStatus == AccountStatus.DELETED);
```

Keep getting this exception:

```
System.Exception: right operand should be detachedQueryInstance.As<T>() - "DELETED"
at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.FindDetachedCriteria(Expression expression)
at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessSubqueryExpression(LambdaSubqueryType subqueryType, BinaryExpression be)
at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessSubquery[T](LambdaSubqueryType subqueryType, Expression`1 expression)
at NHibernate.Criterion.Subqueries.WhereAll[T](Expression`1 expression)
at RBAC.Infrastructure.DataAccess.QueryObject.Implementation.UserQueryObject.FilterByContainerRelationsAreScheduledForDeletion(IQueryOver`2 queryOver) in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\DataAccess\QueryObject\Implementation\UserQueryObject.cs:line 113
at RBAC.Infrastructure.DataAccess.QueryObject.Implementation.UserQueryObject._ExecuteQuery(IQueryOver`2 queryOver) in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\DataAccess\QueryObject\Implementation\UserQueryObject.cs:line 101
at RBAC.Infrastructure.DataAccess.QueryObject.Base.BaseQueryObject`1.ExecuteQuery(ISessionDecorater session) in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\DataAccess\QueryObject\Base\BaseQueryObject.cs:line 20
at RBAC.Infrastructure.DataAccess.GenericDAO.Implementation.GenericDAO.GetByQueryObject[T](IQueryObject`1 queryObject) in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\DataAccess\GenericDAO\Implementation\GenericDAO.cs:line 253
at RBAC.Infrastructure.BusinessService.CleanupModule.Implementation.RBACCleanerActions.CleanUpUsers() in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\BusinessService\CleanupModule\Implementation\RBACCleanerActions.cs:line 59
```

I have googled up, down and sideways for **right operand should be detachedQueryInstance** and other queries as well with no luck.
Hope somebody here knows what is wrong, and how to solve theese issues in the future.

I have also tried this query with no luck:

```
queryOver.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.UserHasContainer).IsNotEmpty
         .JoinQueryOver<ContainerUser>(x => x.UserHasContainer)
         .Where(Subqueries.WhereAll<ContainerUser>(x => x.AccountStatus == AccountStatus.DELETED));
```

Exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression'.
at NHibernate.Impl.ExpressionProcessor.ProcessSubquery[T](LambdaSubqueryType subqueryType, Expression`1 expression)
at NHibernate.Criterion.Subqueries.WhereAll[T](Expression`1 expression)
at RBAC.Infrastructure.DataAccess.QueryObject.Implementation.UserQueryObject.FilterByUsersWereAllTheirFunctionRelationsAreScheduledForDeletion(IQueryOver`2 queryOver) in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\DataAccess\QueryObject\Implementation\UserQueryObject.cs:line 157
at RBAC.Infrastructure.DataAccess.QueryObject.Implementation.UserQueryObject._ExecuteQuery(IQueryOver`2 queryOver) in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\DataAccess\QueryObject\Implementation\UserQueryObject.cs:line 97
at RBAC.Infrastructure.DataAccess.QueryObject.Base.BaseQueryObject`1.ExecuteQuery(ISessionDecorater session) in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\DataAccess\QueryObject\Base\BaseQueryObject.cs:line 21
at RBAC.Infrastructure.DataAccess.GenericDAO.Implementation.GenericDAO.GetByQueryObject[T](IQueryObject`1 queryObject) in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\DataAccess\GenericDAO\Implementation\GenericDAO.cs:line 253
at RBAC.Infrastructure.BusinessService.ADModule.Implementation.DeletionFlagSetter.FlagUsersForDeletionWereAllRelationsAreFlaggedForDeletionForADRegisteredUsers() in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\BusinessService\ADModule\Implementation\DeletionFlagSetter.cs:line 115
at RBAC.Infrastructure.BusinessService.ADModule.Implementation.ActiveDirectorySynchronizer.Synchronize() in c:\APPL\dev\RBAC\Dev\RBAC.Infrastructure\BusinessService\ADModule\Implementation\ActiveDirectorySynchronizer.cs:line 156
```

**EDIT2:**
I think that the equivalent in linq would be this, if i had a list of users.

```
users.Where(x => x.UserHasFunctions.All(y => y.IsDeleted)).ToList();
```

Comment: Note: You are mixing up Linq and QueryOver here. QueryOver might look like Linq but it's a completely different thing.

Comment: thank you for the note, i removed everything about linq and added better tags for the question

Comment: The error message is saying that rather than comparing the left hand side with a scalar value, you should be using a `DetachedCritiera` or `DetachedQueryOver`. From your (deleted) answer below it looks like you might have figured this out. Do you still need some help?

Comment: I think you're right--could you post the SQL you want to generate by any chance?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, no i don't have the sql but i wrote an equivalent linq query for it at the bottom of the question.

PS: A simple Where doesn't give me what I need.
If a User have 10 relations, and only 1 of them
have the AccountStatus set to DELETED, the user will get selected.
But I only want to select the user if all 10 have the
AccountStatus set to DELETED.

Comment: Yep that makes sense. I think I've got something working, one second...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step I usually take when trying to work through a QueryOver query is to come up with the correct SQL. Based on your LINQ query, I think that would look something like this:

```
select
    User.*
from
    User
where
    /* Or whatever "deleted" turns out to be, not necessarily '1' */
    1 = all (select AccountStatus          
             from ContainerUser
             where ContainerUser.UserId = User.Id);
```

Basically get all users where all of that user's `ContainerUser` rows have an `AccountStatus` of deleted.

So in QueryOver you could write something like this:

```
User userAlias = null;

session.QueryOver<User>(() => userAlias)
    .WithSubquery.WhereValue(AccountStatus.DELETED).EqAll(QueryOver.Of<ContainerUser>()
        .Where(uc => uc.User.Id == userAlias.Id)
        .Select(uc => uc.AccountStatus));

// select list, more restrictions, etc.
```

Comment: @furier: No problem! I know QueryOver can be very difficult to write and find documentation on.

Comment: Yeah i'v feel like iv been searching the whole internet but didn't find any helping documentation for exactly this problem. :)